# Prevent Editor Widget auto save

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, editing

I'm writing a feature layer editor demo and I'm using the esri.dijit.editing.Editor class.

According to documentation (https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/editor-amd.html), both attribute edits and geometry edits are saved automatically.

- **Attribute edits** are saved automatically when you change selection, change the focus field, or press enter.
- **Geometry edits** are saved automatically.

The editor is working fine but I wanna add a save button to applyEdits only after click it.

---

Follow my source code and my attempts:

```
var params = {
    settings: {
        map: map,
        geometryService: geometryService,
        templatePicker: templatePicker,
        layerInfos: [
            { 
                featureLayer: featureLayer 
            }
        ],
        toolbarVisible: true,
        enableUndoRedo: true,
        maxUndoRedoOperations: 15,
        createOptions: {
            polylineDrawTools: [
                Editor.CREATE_TOOL_FREEHAND_POLYLINE,
                Editor.CREATE_TOOL_POLYLINE 
            ],
            polygonDrawTools: [
                Editor.CREATE_TOOL_FREEHAND_POLYGON,
                Editor.CREATE_TOOL_POLYGON,
                Editor.CREATE_TOOL_RECTANGLE 
            ]
        },
        toolbarOptions: {
            cutVisible: true,
            mergeVisible: true,
            reshapeVisible: true
        },
        layerInfo: {
            disableGeometryUpdate: true
        }
    }
};

var editorWidget = new Editor(params, "<editor-div-id>");
editorWidget.startup();
```

I've tried to stop event propagation using **dojo/_base/event** but the argument passed in before-apply-edits (FeatureLayer) is not a "valid event".

```
featureLayer.on('before-apply-edits', function(e) {
    // ...
    event.stop(e); // will trow error
});
```

Tried to clear the edits array too but continue saving:

```
featureLayer.on('before-apply-edits', function(e) {
    // ...
    e.adds = [];
    e.updates = [];
    e.deletes = [];
});
```

---

Someone know how to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fix this creating a workaround that override the default applyEdits method with a dummy method and calling the real applyEdits after.

```
// saving the default method for later use
featureLayer.myApplyEdits = featureLayer.applyEdits;

// override with dummy function
featureLayer.applyEdits = function(adds, updates, deletes, callback, errback) {
    // store the arguments in local variable
    // ...

    // create and returns dojo.Deferred to Editor still working
    var deferred = new dojo.Deferred();

    // simulate async execution (.then() callback)
    setTimeout(function() {
        deferred.resolve(true);
    }, 100);

    return deferred;
};
```

And then on button click:

```
featureLayer.myApplyEdits(adds, updates, deletes);
```